# Starting Quarkus in Dev Mode results in NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.threads.JBossExecutors.rejectingExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor

Tags: quarkus

I am currently migrating a java web application to quarkus. After having migrated all code parts and done most adaptions, I wanted to try it out by running the app in dev mode:

```
./mvnw compile quarkus:dev
```

But it crashes right at the beginning with a NoSuchMethodError for java/util/concurrent/Executor:

> 2022-04-01 18:07:06,022 INFO  [io.qua.dep.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain] (main) Attempting to start live reload endpoint to recover from previous Quarkus startup failure
> 2022-04-01 18:07:07,444 INFO  [org.jbo.threads] (main) JBoss Threads version 2.3.3.Final
> 2022-04-01 18:07:07,451 ERROR [io.qua.dep.dev.DevModeMain] (main) Quarkus dev mode failed to start: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.threads.JBossExecutors.rejectingExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.QuarkusExecutorFactory.internalCreateExecutor(QuarkusExecutorFactory.java:48)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.QuarkusExecutorFactory.createExecutor(QuarkusExecutorFactory.java:42)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.(VertxImpl.java:161)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxBuilder.vertx(VertxBuilder.java:225)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder.initialize(VertxCoreRecorder.java:236)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$VertxSupplier.get(VertxCoreRecorder.java:577)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$VertxSupplier.get(VertxCoreRecorder.java:559)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.startServerAfterFailedStart(VertxHttpRecorder.java:208)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.handleFailedInitialStart(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:61)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.startupFailed(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:1145)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:168)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:455)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:66)
> at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:140)
> at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:96)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:132)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.threads.JBossExecutors.rejectingExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:138)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.main(DevModeMain.java:62)
> Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.jboss.threads.JBossExecutors.rejectingExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.QuarkusExecutorFactory.internalCreateExecutor(QuarkusExecutorFactory.java:48)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.QuarkusExecutorFactory.createExecutor(QuarkusExecutorFactory.java:42)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.(VertxImpl.java:161)
> at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxBuilder.vertx(VertxBuilder.java:225)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder.initialize(VertxCoreRecorder.java:236)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$VertxSupplier.get(VertxCoreRecorder.java:577)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.core.runtime.VertxCoreRecorder$VertxSupplier.get(VertxCoreRecorder.java:559)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.VertxHttpRecorder.startServerAfterFailedStart(VertxHttpRecorder.java:208)
> at io.quarkus.vertx.http.runtime.devmode.VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.handleFailedInitialStart(VertxHttpHotReplacementSetup.java:61)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.startupFailed(RuntimeUpdatesProcessor.java:1145)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.firstStart(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:168)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:455)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.IsolatedDevModeMain.accept(IsolatedDevModeMain.java:66)
> at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInCl(CuratedApplication.java:140)
> at io.quarkus.bootstrap.app.CuratedApplication.runInAugmentClassLoader(CuratedApplication.java:96)
> at io.quarkus.deployment.dev.DevModeMain.start(DevModeMain.java:132)
> ... 1 more

The app uses a ScheduledExecutorService, that is being created like this:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class ExecutorInit {
    @Produces
    @ApplicationScoped
    public ScheduledExecutorService getScheduledExecutorService(
            @ConfigProperty(name = "systemRuntime.threadPoolSize") Integer threadPoolSize) {

        return Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(threadPoolSize);
    }
}
```

I suspect this to be involved in the error, but I am currently lacking the understanding why this is happening or what I could possibly do about it.

(if you want to try it out yourself, checkout: https://github.com/labsai/EDDI/tree/version-5)

Maven pom.xml config version:

```
 <properties>
    <dependency.version.lombok>1.18.22</dependency.version.lombok>

    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <jandex-maven-plugin.version>1.2.2</jandex-maven-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.release>11</maven.compiler.release>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>2.7.5.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>2.7.5.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <quarkus.jgit.version>1.2.0</quarkus.jgit.version>
    <quarkus.microprofile.version>2.4.1.Final</quarkus.microprofile.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
    <failsafe-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</failsafe-plugin.version>
    <war-plugin.version>3.3.2</war-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

(https://github.com/labsai/EDDI/blob/version-5/pom.xml)

Comment: Quarkus version: 2.7.5

Comment: Are you sure you updated both the BOM version and the plugin version?

Comment: I believe so, yes. I have added the versions from the pom file in the description @geoand

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know the root cause of the issue described above, but here is what i did to overcome it:

added this dependency to my pom.xml

```
 <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.threads</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-threads</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.2.Final</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
 </dependency>
```

While i had other errors in my migration code, they were not being displayed anywhere until I overcame the described problem by providing this dependency.
After having fixed several other likely unrelated issues, i didn't seem to need this dependency anymore.

While this step is not a real solution, it helped my to proceed further and unveil other issues that were not being displayed at first.